# Unable to define push plugin action callback methods in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, phonegap-pushplugin, ionic-native

**Current behavior:**
I have used push plugin. When i try to define call back methods for push action the following error occured

[ts] Argument of type '"accept"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PushEvent'.

[ts] Argument of type '"reject"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PushEvent'.

**Related code:**

```
this.push.hasPermission()
        .then((res: any) => {
          if (res.isEnabled) {
        console.log('We have permission to send push notifications');
      } else {
        console.log('We do not have permission to send push notifications');
      }

    });
    const options: PushOptions = {
        android: {},
        ios: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
            "categories": {
                "invite": {
                    "yes": {
                        "callback": "accept", "title": "Accept", "foreground": true, "destructive": false
                    },
                    "no": {
                        "callback": "reject", "title": "Reject", "foreground": true, "destructive": false
                    },
                    "maybe": {
                        "callback": "maybe", "title": "Maybe", "foreground": false, "destructive": false
                    }
                },
                "delete": {
                    "yes": {
                        "callback": "doDelete", "title": "Delete", "foreground": false, "destructive": true
                    },
                    "no": {
                        "callback": "cancel", "title": "Cancel", "foreground": false, "destructive": false
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        windows: {},
        browser: {
            pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
        }
     };


     const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);


     pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', JSON.stringify(notification)));

     pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', JSON.stringify(registration)));

     pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));

     pushObject.on('accept').subscribe(obj => console.log('accept a notification', JSON.stringify(obj)));
     pushObject.on('reject').subscribe(obj => console.log('reject a notification', JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

**Other information:**

**package.json info:**

```
{
    "name": "ionic-hello-world",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
        "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/battery-status": "^4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/broadcaster": "^4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/call-number": "^4.0.1",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^3.6.1",
        "@ionic-native/device-orientation": "^4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^4.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^4.0.1",
        "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/network": "^4.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/push": "^4.3.3",
        "@ionic-native/qr-scanner": "^4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/screenshot": "^4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/sms": "^4.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.0.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
        "call-number": "0.0.2",
        "com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot": "^0.1.6",
        "cordova-android": "^6.3.0",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.5.2",
        "cordova-plugin-app-event": "file:node_modules/cordova-plugin-app-event",
        "cordova-plugin-battery-status": "^1.2.4",
        "cordova-plugin-broadcaster": "^2.3.0",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.6",
        "cordova-plugin-device-orientation": "^1.0.7",
        "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.8.11",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.3",
        "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": "^2.5.0",
        "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^2.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.3",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.2",
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.2.1",
        "cordova-sms-plugin": "^0.1.11",
        "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.0.4",
        "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": "^0.8.5",
        "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.1.0",
        "ion-multi-picker": "^1.2.0",
        "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
        "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^6.0.8",
        "phonegap-plugin-push": "^1.10.5",
        "pouchdb": "^6.3.4",
        "pouchdb-find": "^6.3.4",
        "relational-pouch": "^2.1.0",
        "rxjs": "5.0.1",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
        "zone.js": "0.7.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^2.0.2",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.1",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
        "ionic": "3.16.0",
        "typescript": "2.0.9"
    },
    "cordovaPlugins": [
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
        "cordova-plugin-console",
        "cordova-plugin-device",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
    ],
    "cordovaPlatforms": [],
    "description": "new: An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "platforms": [
            "android",
            "ios"
        ],
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {},
            "cordova-sms-plugin": {},
            "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
            "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
            "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
            "cordova-plugin-battery-status": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {
                "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
                "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
            },
            "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
            "call-number": {},
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": {},
            "com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot": {},
            "cordova-plugin-broadcaster": {},
            "phonegap-plugin-push": {
                "SENDER_ID": "85075801930"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It clearly shows the error no?

**Error:**

> Argument of type '"accept"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'PushEvent'.
>
> Argument of type '"reject"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'PushEvent'.

**Solution:**

You cannot use `accept` and `reject` as `PushEvent`.It has `notification`,`registration` and `error` only.

Here is [**the doc**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/):

Comment: Thanks sampath. In push plugin they said like [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#action-buttons-1). Then how can I define calback methods.

Comment: Are you testing this on `iOS` device?

Comment: Yes yes I have tested ios notification actions. Notification received and action buttons showing.  But I am unable try to define action callback.